# W3.CSS how to get a standard header-[left-right]footer layout?

Tags: css, html, layout

I am trying to learn how to use w3.css to structure a page.

First attempt is to get the standard header/left panel/right-panel/footer layout.

I will have then to complicate the issue inserting nested layouts, but that is for later as I'm unable to make this simple example render as I want :(

my current code is quite simple (I have done many attempts bearing basically no difference):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="w3-container w3-indigo">
    <div class="w3-xxlarge">Lorem ipsum -- dolor
      <a href="login.html" class="w3-btn w3-teal w3-large w3-round-xxlarge w3-right">log in</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="w3-display-container">
    <div class="w3-container w3-left w3-border" style="width: 40%">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Res enim se praeclare habebat, et quidem in utraque parte. Sed in rebus apertissimis nimium longi sumus. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Aliter enim nosmet ipsos nosse non possumus. Aliud igitur esse censet gaudere, aliud non dolere. Multoque hoc melius nos veriusque quam Stoici. Nam, ut sint illa vendibiliora, haec uberiora certe sunt. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-right w3-border" style="width: 60%">
      <p>Potius ergo illa dicantur: turpe esse, viri non esse debilitari dolore, frangi, succumbere. Dat enim intervalla et relaxat. Non autem hoc: igitur ne illud quidem. Sed quot homines, tot sententiae; Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="w3-container w3-blue">
    <p>Iam id ipsum absurdum, maximum malum neglegi. Quae cum essent dicta, discessimus. Hanc ergo intuens debet institutum illud quasi signum absolvere. Deprehensus omnem poenam contemnet. Odium autem et invidiam facile vitabis. Uterque enim summo bono fruitur, id est voluptate. </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This code has several issues I'm unable to pinpoint:

1. In header : The button is not aligned with text.
2. Footer: why it's not a footer and fills the space left by the sorter (right) panel? I also tried leaving a gap between the panes (35%-55%) in that case footer is rendered *between* the panes and then below right, as if also footer would be "float".
3. Why the color (w3-blue) is applied to all panes? Shouldn't it apply only to footer?

What am I doing wrong?

Any pointer to relevant documentation/tutorial (understandable by a newbie like me) would be welcome.

Comment: From my perspective, using any CSS framework is a ***really bad idea*** for people wanting to learn HTML and CSS. This includes W3.css and I think they are really not doing learners any good by providing this framework at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Footer  was displaying in the background with the text positioned to fill the gaps where it could and this made the background appear to be blue.

I removed the `w3-display-container` as I couldn't see a reason not to use `w3-container`.

As for the button I Couldnt find something in w3.css to add a `margin-top: 8px` so I added `style="margin-top: 8px"` to the button.

I  would recommend dropping w3.css as it is complicating your learning process. I would start learning HTML and CSS using the W3 resources and once you have mastered the basics if you still feel like using w3.css give it a go, but honestly its a limiting framework.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="w3-container w3-indigo">
    <div class="w3-xxlarge">Lorem ipsum -- dolor
      <a href="login.html" class="w3-btn w3-teal w3-large w3-round-xxlarge w3-right" style="margin-top: 8px">log in</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="w3-container">
    <div class="w3-container w3-left w3-border" style="width: 40%">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Res enim se praeclare habebat, et quidem in utraque parte. Sed in rebus apertissimis nimium longi sumus. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Aliter enim nosmet ipsos nosse non possumus. Aliud igitur esse censet gaudere, aliud non dolere. Multoque hoc melius nos veriusque quam Stoici. Nam, ut sint illa vendibiliora, haec uberiora certe sunt. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-right w3-border" style="width: 60%">
      <p>Potius ergo illa dicantur: turpe esse, viri non esse debilitari dolore, frangi, succumbere. Dat enim intervalla et relaxat. Non autem hoc: igitur ne illud quidem. Sed quot homines, tot sententiae; Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="w3-container w3-blue">
    <p>Iam id ipsum absurdum, maximum malum neglegi. Quae cum essent dicta, discessimus. Hanc ergo intuens debet institutum illud quasi signum absolvere. Deprehensus omnem poenam contemnet. Odium autem et invidiam facile vitabis. Uterque enim summo bono fruitur, id est voluptate. </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually chose w3.css because it's "just" a pre-baked css and I hoped it would not hide the underlying structure. While I'm a newbie in HTML I have a long history in other programming areas. I expected to find some way to emulate other languages "layouts", perhaps something akin to MigLayout (http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf). Apparently there's nothing comparable... or did I miss something?

Comment: The use of CSS flex-box is my choice for layouts such as [this flex-box example](http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/jqzNZq) and a good guide to check out would be [This one by CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `.w3-container` does some clearing of contained floating elements while seemingly `.w3-display-container` only adds `position: relative;` to an element

> `w3-display-container`    Container for w3-display-classes (position: relative)

which is intended to make absolute positioning of inside elements relate to this container.

To understand why this leads to the broken layout, you need to understand the way HTML, floats and positioning works. If you are any serious about learning frontend development, there is no way around that.

So until you have achieved that using vanilla CSS and HTML, **stay away from ANY css frameworks** which only adds an additional layer of complexity that really harms your learning process!

Comment: I still fail to fully grasp .css. That's a fact. I managed to steer clear from it's complexities till now, but, since I need to move into the web-maelstrom, I want to understand what I'm doing (as opposed to relying on tools). My current "philosophical" problem is .css doesn't look (to me) like a human-readable format, but more akin to to .rtf or (to be more lenient) .xml which *can* be hand written, but they're not really meant to be seen by human eyes. Any pointer to good overview documentation (even in the form of a book) would be highly appreciated. Thanks.